# Create release with title using VSTS REST API

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using version 4.1-preview.6 for a call to VSTS' Release API and it looks like whenever it creates a new release, the release's title will not be the expected title, "Release-#" but instead is a negative number like "-1." I'm using PowerShell. I can see in the Web UI that the Release name format is `$(Build.BuildNumber)-$(rev:r)`.

1. Is there a different version of the REST API that fixes this?
2. Or is there a parameter I'm missing in the body?

Request body (excludes variables set earlier in the script and function for Invoke-RestMethod):

```
    $uri = "https://$($accountName).vsrm.visualstudio.com/$($projectName)/_apis/release/releases?api-version=4.1-preview.6"

    $body = @{
        "definitionId" = "$($releaseDefinitionId)"
        "description" = "Creating automated release"
    }
    $body.Add("artifacts", @())
    $artifact = @{
        "alias" = "$($buildDefinitionName)"
        "instanceReference" = @{
            "id" = "$($buildId)"
            "name" = $null
        }
    }
    $body.artifacts += $artifact

    $jsonBody = $body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5

    $response = Invoke-RestCommand -uri $uri -commandType "POST" -jsonBody $jsonBody -personalAccessToken $personalAccessToken
```

Response:

```
id                         : 4
name                       : -4
status                     : active
createdOn                  : 2018-06-12T04:27:18.237Z
modifiedOn                 : 2018-06-12T04:27:18.237Z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check how you define release name format in your definition:

[image]

Comment: I actually cloned this release definition previously (with another set of REST calls), and I can see that in the Release name format field it shows the same Release name format as the screenshot you took: $(Build.BuildNumber)-$(rev:r).

Comment: If you use `$(Build.BuildNumber)-$(rev:r)`, you will get a negative number like "-1". You have to change it to `Release-$(rev:r)` as I screenshot showed.

Comment: Hmm, looks like that did fix it, I wonder if the release is created from the API call then it won't recognize variables defined like Build.BuildNumber. I guess the mystery is solved for now, thank you!